# Perl - What scopes/closures/environments are producing this behaviour?

Tags: perl, closures, environment, subroutine

Given a root directory I wish to identify the most shallow parent directory of any .svn directory and pom.xml .

To achieve this I defined the following function

```
use File::Find;
sub firstDirWithFileUnder {
    $needle=@_[0];
    my $result = 0;
    sub wanted {
        print "\twanted->result is '$result'\n";
        my $dir = "${File::Find::dir}";

        if ($_ eq $needle and ((not $result) or length($dir) < length($result))) {
            $result=$dir;
            print "Setting result: '$result'\n";
        }
    }
    find(\&wanted, @_[1]);
    print "Result: '$result'\n";
    return $result;
}
```

..and call it thus:

```
    $svnDir = firstDirWithFileUnder(".svn",$projPath);
    print "\tIdentified svn dir:\n\t'$svnDir'\n";
    $pomDir = firstDirWithFileUnder("pom.xml",$projPath);
    print "\tIdentified pom.xml dir:\n\t'$pomDir'\n";
```

There are two situations which arise that I cannot explain:

1. When the search for a .svn is successful, the value of `$result` perceived inside the nested subroutine `wanted` persists into the next call of `firstDirWithFileUnder`. So when the pom search begins, although the line `my $result = 0;` still exists, the `wanted` subroutine sees its value as the return value from the last `firstDirWithFileUnder` call.
2. If the `my $result = 0;` line is commented out, then the function still executes properly. This means a) outer scope (`firstDirWithFileUnder`) can still see the `$result` variable to be able to return it, and b) print shows that `wanted` still sees `$result` value from last time, i.e. it seems to have formed a closure that's persisted beyond the first call of `firstDirWithFileUnder`.

Can somebody explain what's happening, and suggest how I can properly reset the value of `$result` to zero upon entering the outer scope?

Comment: Are you using `strict` and `warnings`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `warnings` and then `diagnostics` yields this helpful information, including a solution:

> Variable "$needle" will not stay shared at ----- line 12 (#1)
>
> (W closure) An inner (nested) named subroutine is referencing a
>       lexical variable defined in an outer named subroutine.
>
> When the inner subroutine is called, it will see the value of
>       the outer subroutine's variable as it was before and during the *first*
>       call to the outer subroutine; in this case, after the first call to the
>       outer subroutine is complete, the inner and outer subroutines will no
>       longer share a common value for the variable.  In other words, the
>       variable will no longer be shared.
>
> **This problem can usually be solved by making the inner subroutine
>       anonymous, using the sub {} syntax.**  When inner anonymous subs that
>       reference variables in outer subroutines are created, they
>       are automatically rebound to the current values of such variables.

---

`$result` is lexically scoped, meaning a brand new variable is allocated every time you call `&firstDirWithFileUnder`. 
`sub wanted { ... }` is a *compile-time* subroutine declaration, meaning it is compiled by the Perl interpreter one time and stored in your package's symbol table. Since it contains a reference to the lexically scoped `$result` variable, the subroutine definition that Perl saves will only refer to the first instance of `$result`. The second time you call `&firstDirWithFileUnder` and declare a new `$result` variable, this will be a completely different variable than the `$result` inside `&wanted`.

You'll want to change your `sub wanted { ... }` declaration to a lexically scoped, anonymous sub:

```
my $wanted = sub {
    print "\twanted->result is '$result'\n";
    ...
};
```

and invoke `File::Find::find` as

```
find($wanted, $_[1])
```

Here, `$wanted` is a *run-time* declaration for a subroutine, and it gets redefined with the current reference to `$result` in every separate call to `&firstDirWithFileUnder`.

---

**Update:** This code snippet may prove instructive:

```
sub foo {
    my $foo = 0;  # lexical variable
    $bar = 0;     # global variable
    sub compiletime {
        print "compile foo is ", ++$foo, " ", \$foo, "\n";
        print "compile bar is ", ++$bar, " ", \$bar, "\n";
    }
    my $runtime = sub {
        print "runtime foo is ", ++$foo, " ", \$foo, "\n";
        print "runtime bar is ", ++$bar, " ", \$bar, "\n";
    };
    &compiletime;
    &$runtime;
    print "----------------\n";
    push @baz, \$foo;  # explained below
}
&foo for 1..3;
```

Typical output:

```
compile foo is 1 SCALAR(0xac18c0)
compile bar is 1 SCALAR(0xac1938)
runtime foo is 2 SCALAR(0xac18c0)
runtime bar is 2 SCALAR(0xac1938)
----------------
compile foo is 3 SCALAR(0xac18c0)
compile bar is 1 SCALAR(0xac1938)
runtime foo is 1 SCALAR(0xa63d18)
runtime bar is 2 SCALAR(0xac1938)
----------------
compile foo is 4 SCALAR(0xac18c0)
compile bar is 1 SCALAR(0xac1938)
runtime foo is 1 SCALAR(0xac1db8)
runtime bar is 2 SCALAR(0xac1938)
----------------
```

Note that the compile time `$foo` always refers to the same variable `SCALAR(0xac18c0)`, and that this is also the run time `$foo` THE FIRST TIME the function is run.

The last line of `&foo`, `push @baz,\$foo` is included in this example so that `$foo` doesn't get garbage collected at the end of `&foo`. Otherwise, the 2nd and 3rd runtime `$foo` might point to the same address, even though they refer to different variables (the memory is reallocated each time the variable is declared).

Comment: What a wonderfully clear and informative response. Thank you so much for the time you took to write this, mob.