# Perl scoping - accessing variables in subroutine

Tags: perl

I am doing some code golf, and decided to try and be 'smart' and declare a subroutine where it would have the variables it needs already in scope, to avoid the extra code of having to pass in the arguments:

```
#! perl

use strict;
use warnings;


for my $i(0..1) {
  my @aTest = (1);

  sub foo {
    # first time round - @aTest is (1)
    # second time round - @aTest is (1,2)

    push @aTest, 2;

    # first time round - @aTest is (1,2)
    # second time round - @aTest is (1,2,2)

    my $unused = 0;
  }

  foo();
}
```

`foo` sees the variable `@aTest`, and it has the expected value of `(1)` the first time I enter `foo`, before it pushes `2` onto the array as well. `@aTest` now looks like `(1,2)`.

So far so good.

Then we exit `foo`, and commence the second round of the for loop. `@aTest` is reassigned to `(1)` again.

We enter `foo` for the second time, but `@aTest` retains the value it previously had in `foo` (i.e. `(1,2)`), and then pushes another `2` on to become `(1,2,2)`.

What's going on here?

I assumed that since `@aTest` was in the same scope, it would be referring to the same variable both insed and outside `foo`. So how is it that inside `foo it retains its old value?

Comment: Using B::Deparse does not reveal anything. Have you looked at B::Concise output?

Comment: I can confirm this on Perl 5.20.1. It's interesting to see what happens when you output `@aTest` directly before the call to `foo()`. It's always `( 1 )`. It's as if there is a new `@aTest` lexical to the sub, but it has never been declared. Why does this not fail?

Comment: It works fine if you declare `my @aTest` outside the `for` loop.

Comment: I posted this question into #p5p on irc.perl.org. It creates a closure at compile time apparently, and at the first iteration they are the same, but then they diverge it seems.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839005/perl-what-scopes-closures-environments-are-producing-this-behaviour/8839552#8839552

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048248/variable-foo-will-not-stay-shared-warning-error-in-perl-while-calling-subrout/4048277#4048277, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454266/what-is-the-correct-way-to-fix-this-warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this question into #p5p on irc.perl.org and got an interesting exchange that explains what's going on.

> [15:13:35] <simbabque> can someone explain what's going on in [Perl scoping - accessing variables in subroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025754/perl-scoping-accessing-variables-in-subroutine) ? I've tried to read the output of B::Concise for that program, but my understanding is not strong enough. Could the behaviour we see there be a bug?
>   [15:15:35] <rjbs> &foo is a closure over @aTest.
>   [15:16:33] <haarg> but only the first @aTest, because &foo is created once at compile time
>   [15:17:01] <rjbs> Right.
>   [15:18:09] <rjbs> declaring a named sub inside of anything other than a package or bare block is, in my experience, asking for future heartache
>   [15:18:23] <alh> If you had my $foo = sub { }; $foo->(); it would work as expected
>   [15:18:34] <alh> Or in newer perls, with use feature qw(lexical_subs); my sub foo { } foo() would also work
>   [15:18:35] <simbabque> well the guy said he came across it while golfing
>   [15:19:13] <simbabque> alh: with both of those I had also expected it to   be a closure, but because the sub foo {} gets done at compile time I was confused
>   [15:19:38] <rjbs> lexical subs "do the right thing" with regard to binding
>   [15:19:45] <alh> Still a closure, just re-evaluted every time
>   [15:20:56] <haarg> they share the op tree, but are bound to different variables
>   [15:23:29] <simbabque> I added `say "foo: ".\@aTest;` and `say "out ".\@aTest;` inside and outside the function. That's also weird. the first round both are the same, then foo keeps the same one, and the one in the loop gets a new address and keeps it in subsequent iterations
>   [15:26:48] <alh> Sure, the first run through the loop, the variable that's closed over in the sub is the same one the loop sees
>   [15:27:01] <alh> Then we loop, and get a brand new one, but the sub doesn't (because it's not compiled again)
>   [15:27:46] <simbabque> alh: that makes sense, but why do all subsequent   iterations reuse the same variable but reset it in the loop? Is that just Perl being smart with its memory?
>   [15:28:48] <alh> No, your sub has closed over a variable and maintains a reference to it - so it never goes away and its value is maintained across sub calls
>   [15:29:07] <alh> There's no "my @aTest" in the sub to "reset" the variable
>   [15:29:19] <alh> So it just keeps its value - that's the point of a closure
>   [15:29:21] <simbabque> alh: I meant the one in the loop, not in the sub
>   [15:29:41] <alh> What's happening to the one in the loop that is surprising you?
>   [15:29:52] <simbabque> out: ARRAY(0x2356300) foo: ARRAY(0x2356300) out: ARRAY(0x20978b0) foo: ARRAY(0x2356300) out: ARRAY(0x20978b0) foo: ARRAY(0x2356300) out: ARRAY(0x20978b0) foo: ARRAY(0x2356300)
>   [15:30:13] <simbabque> the first round they are the same
>   [15:30:33] <simbabque> then out (that's the my @aTest in the loop) gets a new address, but the round after that it stays the same
>   [15:30:49] <haarg> the address stays the same
>   [15:30:54] <haarg> that doesn't mean it's the same variable
>   [15:31:02] <haarg> more "gets the same address again"
>   [15:31:12] <simbabque> so Perl just reuses that address?

The output I am referring to is from this modification:

```
for my $i(0..3) {
  my @aTest = (1);

  sub foo {
    push @aTest, 2;
    my $unused = 0;
    print " foo: ".\@aTest;
  }
    print " out: ".\@aTest;

  foo();
}
```

So it's essentially building a closure over the `@aTest` at compile time. In the first iteration, the variable in the loop is the same as in the sub. In all subsequent iterations it creates a new variable in the loop, so we see a fresh `(1)` every time. But the sub does not get compiled again, so the `@aTest` variable in there stays the same and grows.

Answer (score 4):

Before the explanation, the lesson to learn here is to not place *named* subs inside of loops or other subs. (Anonymous subs are fine.)

---

Simplified example:

```
for (1..3) {
   my $var = $_;
   sub foo { say $var; }
   foo();
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
```

---

```
for (1..3) {
   my $var = $_;
   sub foo { say $var; }
   foo();
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for (1..3) {
   my $var = $_;
   BEGIN { *foo = sub { say $var; }; }
   foo();
}
```

As this makes clearer, `$var` is captured *at compile-time*.

But how can `$var` exist at compile-time? Doesn't it get created every pass of the loop? No. Something you have to realize is that `my` creates the variable *at compile-time*. At run-time, it merely places a directive on the stack that causes the variable to be cleared when the directive is popped from the stack. This allows the same `$var` to be used every pass of the loop, which is great because allocating and deallocating scalars is rather expensive.

Now, if what I said what true, then the following would print `3` three times because `@a` would contain three reference to the same variable:

```
my @a;
for (1..3) {
   my $x = $_;
   push @a, \$x;
}

say $$_ for @a;
```

However, it prints `1`, `2` and `3` as expected. Remember that directive `my` places on the stack? It's smarter than I mentioned. If the variable contains an object, or if the variable is still being referenced by something other than the file/sub it's in (e.g. when it's been captured), then it's replaced with a fresh variable instead of being cleared.

What this means,

```
                         First pass            Second pass           Third pass
for (1..3) {             --------------------  --------------------  --------------------
  my $var = $_;          Orig $var assigned 1  New $var assigned 2   Same $var assigned 3
  say \$var;             SCALAR(0x996da8)  !=  SCALAR(0x959b78)  ==  SCALAR(0x959b78)
  sub foo { say $var; }  Prints captured $var  Prints captured $var  Prints captured $var
  foo();
}                        $var is replaced      $var is cleared       $var is cleared
                         because REFCNT=2      because REFCNT=1      because REFCNT=1
```

---

In contrast, try

```
for (1..3) {
   my $var = $_;
   my $foo = sub { say $var; };   # Captures $var at runtime.
   $foo->();
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You nested the subroutine so it will not behave the way you expected.

> Subroutines are stored in a global namespace at compile time. In your example b(); is short hand for main::b();. To limit visibility of a function to a scope you need to assign an anonymous subroutines to a variable.
>
> Both named and anonymous subroutines can form closures, but since named subroutines are only compiled once if you nest them they don't behave as many people expect.

Please read the rest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192228/nested-subroutines-and-scoping-in-perl).

Comment: That doesn't really explain why the variable stays the same. It's true that subs get parsed at compile time, and that the sub is not lexical, but that is not the point. The OP knows that. The question is really why `@aTest` does not get reset. How can there be a new `@aTest` inside the scope of `sub foo` although it was never declared there. The OP is using strict.

Comment: Here you go http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/05/07/mod_perl.html#my()%20scoped%20variable%20in%20nested%20subroutines Why do you want to understand a piece of code that you should never use?

Comment: Aren't you curious? If you don't understand it you can never decide for yourself if you should really never use it. Instead you depend on others telling you. :)

Comment: Perl is an old language and many people have come to the same conclusion at some point. You are just another person that will be wasting their time thinking there is going to be some new discovery that comes out of testing it. But there isn't, Perl has had this activity with nested subroutines since version 5.6 and maybe before that. So all that time before you people have tested and come to the conclusion that if you where to use that it will just cause more bugs or be harder to debug later.

Comment: That's a sad way to look at it. Anyway, [the warning](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Variable-%22%25s%22-will-not-stay-shared) the article you linked shows is not issued at least in my Perl 5.20.1. It's in the _closure_ category, and it is also not shown with `use warnings 'all'`. Back in 2002 when 5.6 was new (as it says there now are warnings) that was issued, but it's not any more. Also, no-one has said anything about wanting to use this. We are all just curious.

Comment: If you wrap the whole code in a subroutine, you will get [the warning](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Variable-%22%25s%22-will-not-stay-shared).

Comment: @simbabque, "Will not stay shared" is not issued here because it's fairly common to place named subs in loops. e.g. `{ my $x; sub foo { return $x ||= ...; } }`. Remember that `{ }` is a loop that executes once (like `for (1) { }`). `next` (ends the loop), `redo` (restarts the loop) and `last` (ends the loop) can all be used in it.